# Method of inputing time series data in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation, precipitation

I have weather stations with its geographical location ( lat,long, ht) along with daily temperature and rainfall data in time series format. I would like to use this meteorological data to interpolate for the remaining area ( no stations area) using around 5 stations.
However, I have faced problem while trying to trying to interpolate using kriging method, as my daily meteorological data is associated with geographical coordinates of the station. ( the input data was generated from CSV file with following column : latitude, longitude, height, temperature, rainfall- so if I have 100 records of temperature and rainfall records of station A, then I have same number of geographical records of station A).

If anyone could suggest me how to input data with time series data in arcmap for single station A without duplicating the location in attribute table?

Comment: The way you're describing it is how time-enabled data works in ArcGIS, at least when it comes to storing time-enabled data in a layer and using ArcGIS' built-in time tools, like the Animation toolbar. If you have one geographic feature (your Station A, for example) with data from 100 different days, you will need to have 100 different Station A features in your layer, each with a different value in its Day field.

Answer (score 2):

You could try building a relational database.

Have just your stations as individual locations, then have the rest of your data as a table. You can perform a relate using the shapes and table.

Might want to consider building a relationship class for this.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004t00000007000000

I hope this helps!